# Java CombSort stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, loops

The program is supposed to randomly generate an increasingly larger sequence of integers, sort them using the Comb Sort algorithm (while counting the number of comparisons), and print the number of comparisons for each sequence sorted. I was given the psuedocode and just had to implement it. Here it is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CombSort{

public static int MAXINT = 10000;
public static int[] intArray = new int[MAXINT];
public static int index;
public static long comparisons;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(index = 10; index <= 10000; index = index * 10)
    {
        comparisons = 0;
        Generate(intArray, index);
        Sort(intArray, index);
        Output(index, comparisons);
    }
}

public static void Generate(int[] valueArray, int count)
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    int temp;
    for(temp = 1; temp <= count; temp++)
    {
        valueArray[temp] = generator.nextInt(MAXINT) + 1;
    }
}

public static void Output(int index, long count)
{
    System.out.println("Number of values in array: " + index);
    System.out.println("Number of comparisons required: " + count);
    System.out.println();
}

public static void Swap(int value1, int value2, int temp)
{
    temp = value1;
    value1 = value2;
    value2 = temp;
}

public static void Sort(int[] value, int tally)
{
    int i, j, gap;
    boolean swapped;

    gap = tally;
    swapped = true;
    while(swapped == true || gap > 1)
    {
        if (Math.floor((gap /1.3 * 100) / 100) > 1)
        {
            gap = (int)Math.floor((gap/1.3*100)/100);
        }
        else gap = 1;

        swapped = false;

        for(i = 1; i <= (tally - gap); i++)
        {
            j = i + gap;
            comparisons++;
            if(value[i] > value[j])
            {
                Swap(value[i], value[j], tally);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

No compile errors. When I run it, it just keeps loading and doesn't ever print anything. Any help is appreciated.

Added note: I inserted some text to be printed, and it looks like the problem is in for loop in the Sort method.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: @vesan, I'm working on that now but not having much luck. I'm just starting out learning programming.

Comment: For starters, your `Swap` (note: should be lowercase `swap`) method probably shouldn't assign to its `temp` parameter. You also have some issues with your scope elsewhere, and you seem to be trying to manipulate your array from index 1 onwards (the first value is at index 0). It's hard to tell what the algorithm is trying to do; I suggest you learn about debugging and step through it, watching how your values change to understand where your algorithm is not doing what you're expecting.

Comment: Good advice there. I think that the `Swap` method is not actually swapping anything except its parameters (which are passed by value, so the original array is unchanged). There may be more issues, though. I believe that debugger + pen and paper is the way to go here.

Comment: Got it. in the swap method, I wasn't actually assigning the new values to the array. Also I fixed the index issue. It looks like it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Per the advice of @vesan and @Amos M. Carpenter, I fixed the array index to start at 0 instead of 1. Also updated the `swap` method to assign the parameter values to the array rather than just reassigning values to new variables.